# Nand2tetris Project 9 out of segment space

Tags: java, jack, nand2tetris

```
class Mario {
    function void main() {
        var int height;
        var int row;
        var int space;
        var int hash;

        let height = 0;
        while (height < 1 | height > 8) {
            do Output.printString("Height: ");
            let height = Keyboard.readInt();
        }

        let row = 0;
        while (row < height) {
            let space = height - row - 1;
            while (space > 0) {
                do Output.printString(" ");
                let space = space - 1;
            }

            let hash = 0;
            while (hash < row + 1) {
                do Output.printString("#");
                let hash = hash + 1;
            }

            do Output.println();
            let row = row + 1;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine, but when running in VMEmulator it shows that I have out of segment space in Mario.main.2 In the vm file it is line - push local 0. I am a total noob,and can't seem to find a solution tot his. How do i fix this?

I have no clue how to fix this :(